# singleton pattern performance drawbacks

Tags: design-patterns

I implemented the *Singleton pattern* in my game to access `instance` functions and variables like they were `static`. All well and good, I can use it conveniently. However, from my understanding, everything has a cost and this ease of use must have some kind of drawback. Question is, is it a lot of expense to frequently use `GameManager.instance.someOtherClass.someVariable` for example? In general, how performance friendly the `Singleton` is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An important part of designing big software systems is to minimize the coupling between components and classes. This can be done through the encapsulation of the implementation of different components. The more components know about each other the higher is the dependency between them.

Using the Singleton Pattern means to be coupled to an implementation class (not to an interface, or to an abstraction). It would be better that each component that is using the GameManager would use a GameManagerInterface instead, so that the implementation can be easily changed or extended. Hiding the dependency to the concrete Singleton Class is difficult because somewhere you have to call the static method.

```
...
IGameManager iGameManager = GameManager.getInstance();
...
```

Using the Singleton Pattern like this is... :

```
 GameManager.instance.someOtherClass.someVariable
```

... is never a good idea. Doing so would couple the calling class to the implementation of each of the called classes. Its best to only communicate with your direct neighbours as said in the "Law of Demeter" 
(a.k.a. "Tell Don't Ask", or "Don't Talk to Strangers").

Maybe for you its time to think about the purpose of the Singleton Pattern: The Singleton Pattern is used to ensure, that there is only one instance of a Class. Nothing more.

Using the static "getInstance" method everywhere in your code leads to hidden dependencies as mentioned before. What you are doing is to use the Singleton Pattern as a replacement for a global variable. This makes your system fragile, because every bit of your code is dependant of the implementation of the singleton class. Changing this class could crash your whole system.

Comment: Though it is no huge program, indeed it is best to learn as early as possible. So say I have a class named `Character`. And this character class wants to know a detail that is stored in the Singleton, say `levelUpBoundary` for how high the character can go. 
Right now I would get this by `GameManager.instance.levelUpBoundary`. What you say is that I should create a variable in my `Character` script like this:
`IGameManager iGameManager = GameManager.getInstance();` just like you said? If so, how exactly to do it?

Comment: First: there is a thing called cohesion, wich means that methods should be close to the data they work on... You should think about the structure. Is it really necessary that the GameManager knows something about the levelUpBoundaries of a character. In my opinion it's an implementation detail of the Character class. Second: as mentioned isn't the singleton pattern a replacement for a global variable what you are using here. You should create the GameManager as a normal object in the main method and inject it as abstraction in the other objects.

Answer (score 3):

There will be no performance drawback if you use frequently the Singleton pattern. From this point of view, use it how many times you like. 
But, if you need this variable often you should think about a redesign. 
Dont't use the singleton if you need a global variable. There is only one reason for the singleton: "it is not allowed to have more than one instance of a class."

So be careful with this pattern. Janis explained that problem very well in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907897/singleton-pattern-performance-drawbacks/41911986#41911986).

Answer (score 0):

In general, Java should be able to optimize away often used accesses like that. I don't think the performance hit should matter until you really have a finished game and start performance tuning while measuring the impact.

The more serious problem could arise when you ever want to use more than one instance of something, then you will have to change your architecture. I'm generally not a friend of singletons and would only use them if I'm 100% sure that there is no way I could ever need a second instance of a class.

Comment: That's a fact right there. Though as for me, when I use a singleton, it is only _that one_ singleton in the entire game/app, not one more. I try not to overuse something and break my stuff up to components for ease of expandability and so on.

Comment: In that case, just go with it. I'm 99% sure that will never have a measurable impact on your performance. That usually comes from graphics operations and network traffic, maybe some heavy algorithms like terrain generation, etc. Definitely not from accessing singletons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, measure singleton and non sigleton approach. In singleton new object is created on the heap once in non singleton new object is created on each invocation.